# Limit the number of response by user using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to limit the number of response to just 3 from 5 of the Social Apps listed. User can only rank 3 social apps out of 5.

Im using questback to create the questionnaire but I need help in creating the condition using javascript

```
<table>   
<tr> 
<td>Instagram</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Twitter</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Facebook</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Linkedin</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Whatsapp</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[class='socialapps']").change(function () {
  var maxAllowed = 3;
  var cnt = $("input[class='socialapps']:checked").length;
  if (cnt > maxAllowed)
  {
     $(this).prop("checked", "");
     alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' social apps!');
 }
});
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: could you please share us the code that you have tried so far

Comment: We need your code to fix your problem.

Comment: I know you want the table to have the rows and columns, but when you use the radio buttons that way, the horizontal row shading implies the radio buttons are related on the horizontal axis. However, you are really asking them to just pick "one-of-each-column". Even if we gave you JS that did what you wanted, I don't think you would get very good survey results.

Comment: Apologize all. I am very new at this. I have provided a sample code for your reference. Again, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for other checked inputs that have the same value using:

```
$inputs = $("input[class='socialapps']");

if ( $inputs.filter('[value="' + val + '"]:checked').length > 1 ) { ... }
```

```js
(function($) {
  $inputs = $("input[class='socialapps']");

  $inputs.change(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val(),
        maxAllowed = 3,
        cnt = $("input[class='socialapps']:checked").length;

    if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
      $this.prop("checked", "");
      alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' social apps!');
    }

    if ($inputs.filter('[value="' + val + '"]:checked').length > 1) {
      $this.prop("checked", "");
      alert('Only one ' + val);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Instagram</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" value="Radio A"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" value="Radio B"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_1" value="Ipod A"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Twitter</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" value="Radio A"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" value="Radio B"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_2" value="Ipod A"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facebook</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" value="Radio A"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" value="Radio B"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_3" value="Ipod A"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Linkedin</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" value="Radio A"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" value="Radio B"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_4" value="Ipod A"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Whatsapp</td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" value="Radio A"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" value="Radio B"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" name="socialapps_5" value="Ipod A"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Chris Happy,

Thank you so much for the solution. How do I make the ranking condition possible? Let's say the first column radio is Rank 1 and so forth. So if user has already chosen first column radio for Instagram, they cant choose it again for other social apps.

Thank you

Comment: @MursidRahman I've updated my answer. I hope it meets your requirements. God bless :)

Comment: OMG Chris! Thank you so much!! That works gorgeously!

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer Harsh. Yeah, there's a struggle between quality and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was interesting, so I took some time to play with solution that has as little code as possible (in the time I had).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var maxAllowed = 3;
  function check(){
    if ($("input.socialapps:checked").length > maxAllowed){
           alert('Select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' social apps!');
           return false;
       }
       return true;
  }
  $("input.socialapps").change(function (e) {
    if (!check()) e.target.checked = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>   
<tr> 
<td>Instagram</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="1" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="2" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="3" name="socialapps_1" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Twitter</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="1" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="2" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="3" name="socialapps_2" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Facebook</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="1" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="2" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="3" name="socialapps_3" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Linkedin</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="1" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="2" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="3" name="socialapps_4" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Whatsapp</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="1" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="2" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="socialapps" value="3" name="socialapps_5" 
value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```